# Maximize a popup with JavaScript in FireFox

Tags: javascript

I'm maximizing a popup with the following JavaScript function:

```
 function expandWindow() {
    window.moveTo(0, 0);
    window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
   }
```

This code works fine in IE and Chrome. However it does not work in FireFox. I've checked and in the FireFox settings it is allowed for the scripts to resize and move windows. However that code does nothing in FireFox. Could anybody help me to figure out what the problem is and how to fix this for FireFox?

Thanks.

Comment: just for fun, try to alert or log the values of `screen.width` and `screen.height` in FF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Firefox 7 announcement](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/09/whats-new-for-web-developers-in-firefox-7/):

> It's no longer possible for a web site to change the default size of a
>   window in a browser, according to the following rules:
>
> - You can’t resize a window or tab that wasn’t created by window.open.
> - You can’t resize a window or tab when it’s in a window with more than
>     one tab.

See also the (recently updated) [MDC entry for window.resizeTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.resizeTo).

Comment: Thanks. However, my popup is opened with window.open method and it is not in a tab, it is a popup and it does not have any other tabs.